# NEST 1.0: See request on Fiddler

Tags: elasticsearch, fiddler, nest

I just updated to NEST 1.0, I have Elastic Search on a remote server (not localhost then) and usually I had no problems seeing the request being sent and received by using Fiddler. After the update, bammm, no requests detected but they are being made without a problem by my app.

Do you have any idea of what it is happening?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatic proxy detection is disabled by default in 1.0.

You need to enable it:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(...)
    .DisableAutomaticProxyDetection(false);
```

Check out [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/809) for some background on why this was changed.

Comment: Cool, it was exactly that. Thanks. By the way I think the issue you were talking about was https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/813

Comment: Great!  Well, #813 is reporting the issue, but #809 (the one I linked) explains the reason for changing the default.