# Get raw query from NEST client

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is it possible to get the raw search query from the NEST client?

```cs
var result = client.Search<SomeType>(s => s
                .AllIndices()
                .Type("SomeIndex")
                .Query(query => query
                    .Bool(boolQuery => BooleanQuery(searchRequest, mustMatchQueries)))
                );
```

I'd really like to debug why I am getting certain results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a way to deserialize Elasticsearch Nest search query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703570/is-there-a-way-to-deserialize-elasticsearch-nest-search-query)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The methods to do this seem to change with each major version, hence the confusing number of answers. **If you want this to work in NEST 6.x, AND you want to see the deserialized request BEFORE it's actually sent**, it's fairly easy:

```cs
var json = elasticClient.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(request);
```

If you're debugging in Visual Studio, it's handy to put a breakpoint right after this line, and when you hit it, hover over the `json` variable above and hit the [magnifying glass thingy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/string-visualizer-dialog-box). You'll get a nice formatted view of the JSON.

Comment: What's your `request`? How do you define it?

Comment: @LxL It's the thing you create when using the [object initialization syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/writing-queries.html). I don't use the fluent API, and this is actually one of the reasons why.

Comment: For those on NEST 6.x and using the fluent API, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50023531/213902) worked for me.

Comment: Alternatively you could also use EnableDebugMode: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-mode.html.

Answer (score 47):

You can get raw query json from `RequestInformation`:

```cs
var rawQuery = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.RequestInformation.Request);
```

Or enable trace on your `ConnectionSettings` object, so NEST will print every request to trace output

```cs
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(elasticsearchUrl));
connectionSettings.EnableTrace(true);
var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
```

NEST 7.x

Enable debug mode when creating settings for a client:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
    .DefaultIndex("index_name")
    .EnableDebugMode()
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

then your `response.DebugInformation` will contain information about request sent to elasticsearch and response from elasticsearch. [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/debug-information.html).

Comment: If you need the query _before_ it is sent: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(elasticClient.Serializer.Serialize(query))`

Comment: result does not have RequestInformation property, I need to add some dependency to access it?

Comment: @RicardoSilva propably you are using NEST 2.x. and answer was written with version 1.x in mind. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554890/nest-2-0-enable-trace/35555214#35555214) one.

Comment: RequestInformation is not there in ISearchResponse :\

Comment: For later versions you might have more luck with `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes)` as detailed in the answer below

Comment: .EnableDebugMode() and .PrettyJson() are life saver, i didn't know that until use them. Give details of all_shard_failed error on my query in response.DebugInformation. Thanks!

Comment: EnableDebugMode indicates that it turns on DisableDirectStreaming and PrettyJson for you, so those two are redundant in the code above.

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti well spotted, will update my answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 30):

For NEST / Elasticsearch.NET v6.0.2, use the ApiCall property of the IResponse object. You can write a handy extension method like this:

```cs
public static string ToJson(this IResponse response)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);
}
```

Or, if you want to log all requests made to Elastic, you can intercept responses with the connection object:

```cs
var node = new Uri("https://localhost:9200");
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(node);
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, new HttpConnection());
connectionSettings.OnRequestCompleted(call =>
{
    Debug.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(call.RequestBodyInBytes));
});
```

Comment: In my case `RequestBodyInBytes` was null. With  `connectionSettings.DisableDirectStreaming(true)` it works -- request/response serializations are not saved in memory by default any more.

Comment: This works in 7.11.0 with above comment on DisableDirectStreaming

Answer (score 23):

In ElasticSearch 5.x, the `RequestInformation.Request` property does not exist in `ISearchResponse<T>`, but [similar to the answer provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43416965/167018) you can generate the raw query JSON using the Elastic Client Serializer and a SearchDescriptor. For example, for the given NEST search query:

```cs
var results = elasticClient.Search<User>(s => s
    .Index("user")
    .Query(q => q                    
        .Exists(e => e
            .Field("location")
        )
    )            
);
```

You can get the raw query JSON as follows:

```cs
SearchDescriptor<User> debugQuery = new SearchDescriptor<User>()
    .Index("user")
    .Query(q => q                    
        .Exists(e => e
            .Field("location")
        )
    )
;

using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    elasticClient.Serializer.Serialize(debugQuery, mStream);
    string rawQueryText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(mStream.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Before making Request, from Nest Query - For Nest 5.3.0 :

```cs
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
elasticClient.Serializer.Serialize(query, stream );
var jsonQuery = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

Edit: It's changed from Nest version 6.x, and you can do below:

```cs
var json = elasticClient.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(request);
```

Comment: +1 for getting the request body _before_ it's sent, but it doesn't _quite_ work in 6.x. `Serializer` changed to `RequestResponseSerializer`. Also, `SerializeToString` was added so the whole thing can be reduced to a [one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50949360/62600).

Answer (score 5):

on nest version 6 use

```
connextionString.DisableDirectStreaming();
```

then on response.DebugInformation you can see all information.

Comment: this is a more relevant answer in 2019

Answer (score 2):

Use `result.ConnectionStatus.Request`.

Comment: I tried this but the there was no data in the byte array.  Have you got an example of how you use it?

Comment: No in real code, but i routinely use it for debugging of queries in visual studio. Try to set breakpoint on 'result =', then make one stepover and then see what do you got in result.ConnectionStatus.

Comment: ConnectionStatus is not there in ISearchResponse :\

Answer (score 2):

When using NEST 7 and you don't want to enable debug mode.

```
public static string GetQuery<T>(this IElasticClient client, SearchDescriptor<T> searchDescriptor) where T : class
    {
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            client.RequestResponseSerializer.Serialize(searchDescriptor, ms);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to get raw request/response through code, I find it much easier to analyze it with fiddler. 
The reason is that I can easily analyze raw request, response, headers, Full URL, execution time - all together without any hassle of code changes.
Here's some reference links in case someone unfamiliar with fiddler wants to check details:
#1 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-fiddler.html

#2 [NEST 1.0: See request on Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930987/nest-1-0-see-request-on-fiddler)

#3 https://newbedev.com/how-to-get-nest-to-work-with-proxy-like-fiddler

Answer (score 0):

How about using  [Fiddler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_(software)) ?!  :)