# Nest 2.0 enable trace

Tags: nest

I am on updating to the latest `Nest` version. Since I am getting not the expected results I am searching for replacement of the `EnableTrace()` method which was a method of `ConnectionSettings` on previous versions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`EnableTrace()` will be back, but it's not available yet([have a look](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1762)).

For now you can use this code to print out information about request and response:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
    .DefaultIndex(indexName)
    .DisableDirectStreaming()
    .OnRequestCompleted(details =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("### ES REQEUST ###");
        if(details.RequestBodyInBytes != null) Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(details.RequestBodyInBytes));
        Debug.WriteLine("### ES RESPONSE ###");
        if (details.ResponseBodyInBytes != null) Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(details.ResponseBodyInBytes)); 
    })
    .PrettyJson();
```

[Make sure](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Tests/ClientConcepts/LowLevel/Connecting.doc.cs#L102) you have set `.DisableDirectStreaming()` on `ConnectionSettings`.

Hope it helps.