# Nest serialize elasticsearch Terms Query request

Tags: nest

I'm using NEST 2.0.2 to query ElasticSearch.
Really great API, thanks for the effort, but needs documentation update I think.
Anyways,

1. I want to serialize my request. I could not find any info, there are some stackoverflow questions but it's about older versions, and api changed.
2. I want to write a "terms query". But could not succeed.

The working sense DSL is below.

```
GET myindex/mytype/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field1": {
              "value": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "field2": [
              16,
              17,
              18,
              19
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "termsAggField2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field2",
        "size": 20
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sumAggField3": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "field3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the terms query code is below. DSL works in sense, but the query does not working. The "not in" does not filter the output.

```
List<QueryContainer> must_not = new List<QueryContainer>();

must_not.Add(Query<mytype>.Terms(trms => trms.Terms(new string[] { "16", "17", "18", "19" })));

var resultTermsSum = b1.ElasticClient.Search<mytype>(q=>q.SearchType(SearchType.Count)
                .Query(q2 => q2.Bool(
                    b => b.MustNot(must_not.ToArray())
                    )
                )
                .Aggregations(a => a.Terms("termsAggField2", terms => terms.Field("field2").Size(20)
                .Aggregations(a2 => a2.Sum("sumAggField3", sum => sum.Field("field3"))))));
```

ie why I want to see the serialized request and see my problem.

thanks.
regards.

**Edit:** It's now working with the following update. It'd be great if I could serialize ;)

```
List<QueryContainer> must_not = new List<QueryContainer>();

            short [] valueCollection = new short[] { 16, 19, 99, 100 };

            must_not.Add(Query<mytpe>.Terms(trms => trms.Field("field2").Terms(valueCollection)));

var resultTermsSum = b1.ElasticClient.Search<mytype>(q=>q.SearchType(SearchType.Count)
                .Query(q2 => q2.Bool(
                    b => b.MustNot(must_not.ToArray())
                    )
                )
                .Aggregations(a => a.Terms("termsAggField2", terms => terms.Field("field2").Size(20)
                .Aggregations(a2 => a2.Sum("sumAggField3", sum => sum.Field("field3"))))));
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554890/nest-2-0-enable-trace) is the answer how you can check you request to ES. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Rob thanks. Your comment solved my problem. Appreciate it