# catch query sent to elasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to catch the query sent to elastic, i am using nest 7.6.1.
How can i see the query of the request. Here is the code :

```
ISearchResponse<Document> initialResponse = this.clientBundle.GetClient().Search<Document>
                (
                    scr => scr
                     .From(0)
                     .Take(scrollSize)
                     .Query(q =>
                                q.Bool(y => boolQuery)
                            )
                     .Scroll(scrollTimeout));
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28940234/290460) question.

Answer (score 1):

By default, NEST serializes directly to the request stream and deserializes from the response stream, but this can be disabled globally or on a per-request basis such that these are buffered in memory and are available in the API call details on the response

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var searchResponse = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .RequestConfiguration(r => r
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
    )
);

var requestJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(searchResponse.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);
```

If you're wanting to see all requests and responses, you may want to set `DisableDirectStreaming(...)` on `ConnectionSettings` and configure a delegate on using [`OnRequestCompleted(...)` to print these out](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-on-request-completed.html)

```cs
var defaultIndex = "default_index";
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
    .PrettyJson()
    .OnRequestCompleted(callDetails =>
    {
        if (callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri} \n" +
                $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        if (callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                     $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                     $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                     $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
        }
    });

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var searchResponse = client.Search<object>();
```

This is essentially what `.EnableDebugMode()` on `ConnectionSettings` does.

---

If you want to be able to see requests *without* making an actual request, you can serialize the request with the `RequestResponseSerializer`

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

ISearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchDescriptor<object>()
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("foo")
            .Query("bar")
        )
    );

var json = client.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(searchRequest);
```

With this approach, the request should be cast to the request interface to serialize properly e.g. `SearchDescriptor<T>` -> `ISearchRequest`.

An alternative approach is to use `InMemoryConnection`

```cs
var defaultIndex = "default_index";
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new InMemoryConnection())
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
    .DisableDirectStreaming();

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var response = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("foo")
            .Query("bar")
        )
    )
);

var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);
```

As before, `OnRequestCompleted(...)` can be used with this approach to capture all requests.